# Template function overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void    func(int&)
{
  std::cout << "mutable" << std::endl;
}

void    func(const int&)
{
  std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void    tpl_func(T&)
{
  std::cout << "mutable_tpl" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void    tpl_func(const T&)
{
  std::cout << "const_tpl" << std::endl;
}

class number
{
public:
  operator int&()
  {
    return nb_;
  }

  operator const int&()
  {
    return nb_;
  }

private:
  int   nb_ = 42;
};

int     main()
{
  number n;

  func(n);     // This produces: error: call to 'func' is ambiguous
  tpl_func(n); // This compiles fine
}
```

*Tested with clang3.5*

**Questions:**

- Why is the overload resolution for the template functions not ambiguous ?
- What rules determine which overload is chosen ?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what does tpl_func print?

Comment: @Creris It prints "mutable_tpl"

Comment: well yes as mentioned below with two answers, it is actually not ambiguous. It would most likely become ambiguous if you called `tpl_func<int>(n);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in `func(n)` there's an implicit function call (the int-conversion operator) which is ambiguous (you could choose any of the two) and in `tpl_func(n)` you're NOT int-converting, i.e. the template deduces to `tpl_func<number>(number &)` since `n` is lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

`func(n);` requires a conversion, both `func` are viable and overload is ambiguous.

`tpl_func(n);` has an exact match (`template<typename T> void tpl_func(T&)`).